# CSS display:inline-table = strange 1px margin right on div

Tags: css, cross-browser

i'm writing my little css framework but i got a strange problem, check this jsfiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net/76y8B/

as you can see the red div has `1px margin right` but i setted all to `margin:0;`

Any help please?

Comment: Your div is 96% in width, change it to 100% and rejoice.

Comment: @limelights (width : 96%) + (padding :0 2% 0 2%)  == width 100% IMO :D

Comment: strange, but I cant see margin in fiddle. which browser>?

Comment: inline-table, seems to be your issue

Comment: @AlexThomas yeah but you know i need some solution XD eheh joking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your making a calculation error. You've sized your `div` to 96% of the body. Say the body is 1000 pixels wide, that means the div is now 960 pixels. You then give it a padding of 2% on both left and right side, meaning 2% of 960 pixels, or 19.2 pixels on both ends. 960+19.2+19.2 = 998.4 pixels total width. That's where the minor gap comes from.

The only way to fix this without fixing other markup is to correct for the calculation origin of the padding, ie. set the paddings not to `(100-96)/2` but `((100/96)-1)/2` or 2.08333%. The following thus solves the gap:

```
.heading {
    padding: 13px 2.08333% 8px;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `border-box` to change how these values are calculated, see [this other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20742353/1729885).

Comment: yeah i think this is the problem but and how the hell i can make this to work so?

Comment: added the extra calculation

Comment: actually i dunno if to accept your or already accepted answer since both border-box solution and your solution works great :(

Comment: `border-box` is just as valid as solution. I just also explained what your original problem was  ;)

Comment: ok i accept your , both solutions are awesome your own involves less code so just for that eheh :P , thank you

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to set 100% width and a cooler `box-sizing`: `border-box`.

```
.heading {
    /* new stuff */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    /* end of new stuff */    
    clear: both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 28px;
    padding: 13px 2% 8px;    
}
```

<kbd>[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/76y8B/3/)</kbd>

Read more on [Box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/), and on the [differences between the W3C Box model and the Traditional Box Model](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html):

> **Box models**
>
> - In the `W3C box model`, the width of an element gives the `width` of the content of the box, excluding `padding` and `border`.
> - In the `traditional box model`, the width of an element gives the `width` between the borders of the box, including `padding` and `border`.

Comment: this actually seems to work very well, but can you explain me the changes please?

Comment: i mean this actually fixing :O thank you i never heard before of border-box :/

Comment: added some link, glad that helped

Comment: i'm sorry i accepted the other answer just cause involves less code , but thank you a ton for this solution too!!

Comment: +1 from me as well anyway for the proper alternative solution  :)

Comment: Thanks @NielsKeurentjes. sbaaaang, don't worry about that :) P.S:  `* { box-sizing: border-box;}` FTW ;)

Comment: There is no `-ms-box-sizing: border-box`, and the `-webkit-` prefix is generally not needed anymore. The `-moz-` prefix is still required though.

Comment: You should tell prefixr about that :)

Answer (score 0):

The element has the display property `inline-table`. Is the per design? That, in combination with the 2%+2%+96% logic is what is causing the margin, change it to `inline-block` and you’ll see.

Comment: yeah i use it per design , cause then i can put span1 , span2 etc that all looks like display-table-cell; any way to remove that margin? i can't use display:inlne-block; cause it brokes span1, span2 etc

Comment: @sbaaaang tables don’t work well with padding. Remove the padding and set width to 100%.

Comment: yeah but i need then a new div with padding for the content :/

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline-table` in `.row-fluid` is causing problem.

Remove it or write `display:block`.

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/76y8B/1/)